# GRASS GIS installed add on does not show in Modules>addons

Tags: grass-gis, add-ons

I'm using GRASS GIS 7.2.1 64 bit in Windows 10 and however new add-ons can be installed most of the installed ones do not show in the "Module" window under the category "Addons":

[image]